# wget changes downloaded file size

Tags: debian, python, wget

I'm using `wget` to download Excel file with `xlsx` extension. The thing is that when I want to deal with the file using `openpyxl`, I get the following error: *"BadZipfile: File is not a zip file"* But when I download the file manually using fire fox, I don't have any problems.

So I checked the difference between the two downloaded files. I found that the manually one's size is much bigger (269.2 kB) compared to the wget one (7.3 kB), though both have the same content when moved to Win and open by MS Excel.

I don't add any options for the `wget` just use it like `wget <downloadLink>`

**What's wrong with wget and Excel files?**

Comment: With that low file size, I assume that `wget` did not really download the Excel file but an HTML error page. This might be caused by missing cookies or too many redirects.  Please have a look into the file `wget` downloaded using `file` or a text editor and add the information to your question.

Comment: @Dubu thanks for the reply. But I copied the two files to Windows to open on MS Excel and the content is the same in both files.

Comment: What protocol are you using to download the file (is it, by any chance, ftp)?

Can you please post the output of `wget -S <downloadlink>`?

Comment: @AndrásKorn sorry, can't do that. It's company confidential

Comment: So anonymize/obfuscate it. The specific URL or the filename are not important, only what http headers like content-type, content-length etc.